# Workflow Reference issues between Sandbox and Production

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Lets say I create a workflow that sends an e-mail in Sandbox.  I create the contact and use this contact as the send to e-mail in the workflow.

I export and import this patch into production.  The workflow deactivates because the contact doesn't exist in production.

Let say I create the contact in production and then export/import the patch.  The workflow still deactivate because the id's mismatch.

How do I go about creating a workflow using references like this without the workflow breaking when I push it to production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export/import the data including the Record GUID using Source instance CSV file into Target instance. [Read more](http://crmkrm.blogspot.com/2019/01/copying-records-with-guid-in-microsoft.html)

Otherwise you can use [Configuration Migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/manage-configuration-data)